# Search in Single-Token-Field using Lucene.NET

Tags: search, lucene.net, lucene, exact-match

I´m using Lucene.NET 3.0.3 for indexing the content of word-, excel-, etc. documents and some custom fields for each document.
If I index a field named **"title"** as **Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED** the Lucene-Index stored the field in correct form. The hole title is stored in a single token. That´s what I want.

e.g.    **title of document is "Lorem ipsum dolor"**
**field in Lucene-index: "Lorem ipsum dolor"**

If I search using exact search in this field I get no results.
My searchterm looks like: *title:"Lorem ipsum dolor"*
For searching i´m use the same StandardAnalzer.

Why I can´t find the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StandardAnalyzer` is sensitive to whitespace, among other delimiters. That is, it tokenizes the search term into three tokens:

```
( Lorem, ipsum, dolor )
```

But you indexed field `title` using `Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED` so none of the three tokens above can match the single token in this field:

```
( Lorem ipsum dolor )
```

Use `KeywordAnalyzer`, which tokenizes the entire field value as a single token. As always, you need to use the same analyzer for both indexing and searching.

Comment: That´s works fine. Is it possible to search using wildcards in KeywordAnalyzer?

Comment: Yes `KeywordAnalyzer` works with wildcards so you should get the correct match with search expression `title:lorem*`. But I think `title:"lorem ips"*` is not a valid search expression (phrase query with wildcard) because the phrase query does not support wildcards; you will either get an error or no match.